# POCO did not rotate on specified time

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

The program can't rotate the program log using the "rotate" property and "00:00" as the value. Run the program one day and the next day without the result of the rotation. I have tried it for several hours and have not had success either. On the other hand, it works correctly for me if I use "daily", but of course, I am interested in the rotation being carried out every day at 00:00. I would appreciate your help, any contribution will be highly valued.

Using poco-1.11.1

OS: Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon
Version: 5.0.7
linux core: 5.4.0-generic
Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 5700U

The provisionally developed code is:

```
// Configuracion canal fichero log
pCanalFich1->setProperty("path", "log.log");
pCanalFich1->setProperty("rotation", "00:00");   // CHECK THIS LINE PLEASE. 
pCanalFich1->setProperty("archive", "timestamp");
pCanalFich1->setProperty("times", "utc");
pCanalFich1->setProperty("purgeCount", "5");
```

Comment: Sounds like you should raise this issue with the maintainers of the library.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a `FileChannel`

See Slide 35 of the Logging slides [here](https://pocoproject.org/slides/110-Logging.pdf) to see what you can set the rotation to.
I think you want:

```
pCanalFich1->setProperty("rotation", "daily");
```